# System::Currency and C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, currency

I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder XE10 for building an application that does some monetary calculations.

While trying to use the System::Currency datatype I am facing a couple of problems.

Q1: Why does the calculation of the modulus fail when using the "%" operator?

```
System::Currency TaxValue = 1.665;
System::Currency Rest = 0;

// Correct result: Rest will be 0.005 when converted to double
Rest = TaxValue - ( TaxValue / 100 * 100 );

// Incorrect result: Rest is the same as TaxValue
Rest = TaxValue % 100;
```

> Edit: I have been totally fooled by the debugger's output where the
>   System::Currency's value is shown in its integer represention multiplied
>   by 10.000.
>
> What I really expected to see was:
>
> ```
> Rest = (TaxValue * 10000) % 100;
> ```
>
> ==> Now Rest is 50, which is exactly what I expected.

Q2: How can I do a correct banker's rounding with the Curreny data type?

Examples:

```
1.664 => 1.66
1.665 => 1.67
1.666 => 1.67
```

Herwig

Comment: `System::Currency` is not a part of standard C++. Are you, by any chance, compiling as C++/CLI instead of C++?

Comment: I know. System::Currency is part of the Borland/Embarcadero Framework.

Comment: oh, I see. In that case - please elaborate on what _incorrect result_ is. I.e. What did you expect, what did you get, why did you expect the code to behave differently.

Comment: The result was correct, therefore my question was not legal (other words for "stupid"). I have been misleaded by debugger output, where each System::Currency value is displayed in its integer representation multiplied by 10.000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Why does the calculation of the modulus fail when using the "%" operator?

`System::Currency` operates with a precision of 4 decimal places.  Your example expects 2-digit precision instead.

`System::Currency` maintains its precision without rounding errors by internally multiplying input values by `10000` and then using integer math instead of floating-point math to manipulate values.

When you initialize `TaxValue` with `1.665`, its internal `Val` member (which is an `__int64`) is set to `(1.665 * 10000) = 16650`. Here is what that constructor looks like:

```
__fastcall Currency(double val) {Val = _roundToInt64(10000 * val);}
```

When you then perform `TaxValue % 100`, the `%` operator is implemented like this:

```
Currency __fastcall operator %(int rhs) const
{return Currency(static_cast<int>(Val % (10000 * (__int64)rhs))) / 10000;}
```

The first part creates a temp `Currency` object that is initialized with an `int` value of `(16650 % (10000 * 100)) = 16650`, which gets multiplied by `10000` to `166500000` by the constructor of the temp object:

```
__fastcall Currency(int val) {Val = 10000*(__int64)val;}
```

The second part then divides the temp by `10000`. The `/` operator is implemented like this:

```
Currency& __fastcall operator /=(const Currency& rhs)
{Val *= 10000; Val /= rhs.Val; return *this;}

Currency __fastcall operator /(int rhs) const
{Currency tmp(*this); return tmp /= Currency(rhs);}
```

Thus producing a final `Currency` object whose `Val` has been set to `(166500000 * 10000) / (10000 * 10000) = 16650`.

When that final `Currency` is then assigned to `Rest` and converted to `double`, the value is divided by `10000`, thus producing `1.665`:

```
__fastcall operator double() const {return ((double)Val) / 10000;}
```

> Q2: How can I do a correct banker's rounding with the Curreny data type?

Have a look at the `System::Round()` function, which uses banker's rounding.

If you want more control over the rounding, use the `System::Math::RoundTo()` function, or find a 3rd party rounding function.

There are several other questions on StackOverflow that deal with `Currency` rounding, for instance:

[How to get Delphi Currency Type to Round like Excel all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965759/)

[rounding a currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023973/)

(`System::Currency` is C++Builder's wrapper for Delphi's native `Currency` type).